# iOS Swift Like Button in UITableView 's Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` in my app. and in my app users can like a post (best example is instagram). when I like a post my button state change to active and button's color change. but when I scroll the `tableView` button state back to normal. I know it happen because cell reload again, but what is the best solution for this problem? am I have to overtime that I press like button app send like request and tableview reloadData? (this is not good for server)

EDIT: I have a flag for button, but when I press like button I have to send request and fetch dataArray again. but how can change button state and send like request but not fetch dataArray. it will happen when user manually refresh data.

thanks.

Comment: What is the request that you have to send, why do you have to fetch dataArray? And what is dataArray?

Comment: Are you using Firebase?

Comment: @FredericP like request send me back a true or false that user like a post or not

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp no I use Alamofire

Answer (score 1):

You can set using if and else condition. see below example

```
if model.data.isFav == true
{
    btnFav.selected = true
}
else
{
    btnFav.selected = false
}
```

Comment: but when I press like I have to send request and fetch dataArray again. but how can change button state and send like request but not fetch dataArray. it will happen when user manually refresh data.

Comment: Simple logic. You can call api change status of button in success response.

Comment: But I don't want to tableView reloadData every time I press like button

Comment: reload only that row for which the button is pressed. dont reload the whole table

Comment: You can reload particular cell using indexPath self.tableview.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)

Answer (score 0):

If you have any flag for button with Posts in your dataArray from which you are loading cells data then you can use that flag to set the color of button. It will take care at the time of scroll.

Comment: yes i have a flag for button, but when I press like I have to send request and  fetch dataArray again. but how can change button state and send like request but not fetch dataArray. it will happen when user manually refresh data.

Answer (score 0):

Set button type to custom in the navigation inspector, then set the background image for default and selected. then use the code below:

```
//    MARK: Set fav button Action
    func setFavButtonAction(_ sender : UIButton) {
        print(sender.tag)
        if sender.isSelected == true {
            sender.isSelected = false
        }else{
            sender.isSelected = true
        }
    }
```